# Will a lump sum payout reduce charitable contribution?

Tags: united-states, annuity, charitable-contributions, lump-sum

By receiving a lump sum payout from an annuity, which increases my AGI, will it reduce the percentage I can claim for a charitable contribution?

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can claim up to 50% of your AGI as charitable deduction.

Comment: More specifically by receiving a lump sum payout from an annuity, which increases my AGI to $600,000 and if I make a $175,000 charitable contribution, how much will it lower my tax bracket?  Thank you.

Comment: According to http://www.forbes.com/sites/moneybuilder/2013/01/05/updated-2013-federal-income-tax-brackets-and-marginal-rates/, the top tax bracket is 39.6%, for income $400,000 and above (single filers). So it wouldn't lower your tax BRACKET at all, unless you are married and filing jointly.